# Python Flask server only connects to MySQL in docker host network_mode

Tags: python, mysql, docker, nginx, flask

I have a simple Python Flask web server, running in a docker container along with an Nginx reverse proxy, and a MySQL database.

When the docker compose is run in network_mode: 'host', everything (nginx-python-mysql) works fine.

But when it is switched to bridge networking, Nginx and the python endpoint app seem to work fine, but the python app is unable to connect to the MySQL instance.

I am exposing the MySQL port 3306. Everything is running on a CentOS-7 vm. 
The Python Flask app is running on an gunicorn Python WSGI HTTP Server instance. The MySQL database is based on tutum/mysql.

I have tried both pymysql and SQLAlchemy clients on the python endpoint, and I can only get them to connect to the mysql server in host network_mode.

And as far as I can tell from the docker instance info, the MySQL container is fine, and on the same network as the python endpoint container.

Unfortunately, this is all running on an air gaped server, so its difficult to post the config files here, but the only difference between the host and bridge mode settings is that the nginx ssl config proxy pass has https://endpoint instead of https://localhost, and connecting via https to the python app works in both host and bridge modes. The python app connects to the mysql database on host 0.0.0.0

What could cause the python app to mysql database connection problem to only work in host mode?

Comment: Are you publishing ports correctly when running your docker containers? Maybe you should use docker networks and connect using the contaner name. Are they all running on a single machine? Which host do you start gunicorn with: 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1? There are too many unknowns.

Comment: I am exposing the MySQL port 3306. Everything is running on a CentOS-7 vm. I believe that gunicorn is started with 127.0.0.1, but I will have to check on that tomorrow when I am back in the office.  I know I must be missing something simple, but there are almost no differences in the config between the host and bridge modes.  In host mode, the app server connects to the mysql db on host 0.0.0.0. I tried many different things in bridge mode, including 'mysql', the instance name alias, localhost, the actual IP, etc., but could not get it to connect.

Comment: You could create a docker network `docker network create network_name` and connect containers to it `docker network connect network_name container_name`. Without docker networks or `--net=host` you just request `localhost` and the service's port.

Comment: Thank you rocksteady, I will try that when I get back to the office tomorrow.

Comment: I think the light is beginning to shine through. This is not a docker network problem, but a mysql user security issue. I think its expecting user@localhost but getting user@remotehost when I connect in bridge mode.

Comment: Thank you rocksteady! When I changed the MySQL user account from user@localhost to user@%, then the python app can connect in both network and bridge modes.